# PHP output from SQL into a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have a query that works (see query results) temporarily taken out I don't have enough points for more than two links

However, when I try to output in PHP the category name is the same for both the offeredcategory.categoryName and wantedcategory.categoryName for categoryName on output to a table (see screenshot):

[image: HTML output]

I'm trying to use the alias in the query to output categoryName differently for offered and wanted. 
I've also tried using `$row["offeredcategory.categoryName"]` and `$row["wantedcategory.categoryName"]` which yields an error:

> *Notice: Undefined index: offeredcategory.categoryName in C:\Program Files (x86)*

```
// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, offeredcategory.categoryID, offeredcategory.categoryName, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, wantedcategory.categoryID, wantedcategory.categoryName
    FROM customers
    INNER JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    INNER JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredcategory ON offeredcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS wantedcategory ON wantedcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<table>
                <tr><th></th><th colspan=2>OFFERING</th><th colspan=2>WANTING</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
        //need to prevent SQL injection using ...

         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
             {

             echo
            '<tr>
                <td><img src="images/'.$row["fileUploadLocation"]. '" width="80" height="80" class="descImage"/></td>
                <td>' ."<h6>" . $row["categoryName"]. "</h6>" . "<br>"
                      . $row["servicesOfferedTitle"]. '</td>
                <td>' . $row["servicesOfferedDescription"]. '</td>
                <td>' . $row["categoryName"]. "<br>"
                      . $row["servicesWantedTitle"]. '</td>
                <td>' . $row["servicesWantedDescription"]. ' </td>
                <td>' . $row["location"]. '</td>
            </tr>';
         }
         echo "</table>";
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }
```

I've now tried as suggested changing alias from joins to Select but now the joins won't work 
Haven't to the $row part yet.

I've now tried as suggested changing alias from joins to Select but now the joins won't work (see screenshots):

[image: error 1 using Select alias in join]

Haven't to the $row part yet.

**from manasschlcatz**
Next tried 2nd suggestion but yields error:

> Notice: Undefined index: offeredName in C:\Program Files (x86)

```
$sql = "SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, offeredName.categoryID, offeredName.categoryName, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, wantedName.categoryID, wantedName.categoryName
FROM customers
    INNER JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
    INNER JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredName ON offeredName.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS wantedName ON wantedName.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID" ;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>
            <tr><th></th><th colspan=2>OFFERING</th><th colspan=2>WANTING</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
    //need to prevent SQL injection using ...

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
         {

         echo
        '<tr>
            <td><img src="images/'.$row["fileUploadLocation"]. '" width="80" height="80" class="descImage"/></td>
            <td>' . $row["offeredName"]. "<br>"
                  . $row["servicesOfferedTitle"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $row["servicesOfferedDescription"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $row["wantedName"]. "<br>"
                  . $row["servicesWantedTitle"]. '</td>
            <td>' . $row["servicesWantedDescription"]. ' </td>
            <td>' . $row["location"]. '</td>
        </tr>';
     }
```

Comment: Alias it in your select statement, not the join. Like "Select offeredcategory.categoryID as offered". And then get it like "$row['offered']"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Having trouble with joins now. See screenshots on edit of post

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate field names: `offeredcategory.categoryName`and `wantedcategory.categoryName` will both be retrieved `$row['categoryName']` so only one will show up - categoryName is ambiguous but not rejected by MySQL because the SQL statement is clear and the problem is processing the results in PHP. Simple solution is:

```
offeredcategory.categoryName as offeredName
wantedcategory.categoryName as wantedName
```

and retrieve with `$row['offeredName']` or `$row['wantedName']` depending on what you actually want to display.

Complete SQL becomes:

```
SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.categoryselectedID, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, offeredcategory.categoryID, offeredcategory.categoryName as offeredName, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, wantedcategory.categoryID, wantedcategory.categoryName as wantedName
FROM customers
INNER JOIN ads ON ads.customerId = customers.customerID
INNER JOIN categoriesselected ON categoriesselected.adID = ads.adID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredcategory ON offeredcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS wantedcategory ON wantedcategory.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID";
```

Comment: query works great but retrieval doesn't work I get Notice: Undefined index: offeredName.categoryName in C:\Program Files (x86) <td>' . $row["offeredName"]. "<br>"

Comment: Query works great (LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS offeredName ON offeredName.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID) 
 but retrieval doesn't work:  I get Notice: Undefined index: offeredName.categoryName in C:\Program Files (x86).   I'm using this in the html <td>' . $row["offeredName"]. "

Comment: @Dan-Currie The index is ONLY the "as" fieldname, not the tablename (implied) or original fieldname (irrelevant). An "Undefined index" should only happen from an array reference, not SQL statement. Are you sure you aren't using `$row['offeredName.categoryName']` by mistake?

Comment: @manasschlacatz. See the second block of code please. I highlighted your name where it starts. I get the same error (undefined index) referencing $row['offeredName'] and $row['wantedName']. The problem is EITHER in the SQL, which as you mentioned will still work OR in the $row. I'm stuck.

Comment: @DanCurrie You got things a bit confused - you changed the "as" tablename instead of changing the fieldname to use "as".

Comment: @manasschlacatz I'm confused and don't know where to put the AS is it the SELECT or JOIN. I've tried this:  LEFT OUTER JOIN categories.categoryID AS offeredName ON categories.categoryID = categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories.categoryID AS wantedName ON categories.categoryID = categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID

Comment: @DanCurrie The JOIN phrases are fine as you originally had them. The change is in the field list in the first part (between SELECT and FROM). Try the full SELECT statement as I posted in the answer.

Comment: @manasschlacatz I get #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'categories'

Comment: @manasschlacatz I get #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'categories'  SELECT customers.*, ads.*, categoriesselected.offeredcategoryID, 
categories.categoryName as offeredName, categoriesselected.wantedcategoryID, categories.categoryName as wantedName

Comment: @manasschlacatz. Thank you so much I didn't get that I had to alias both in the select and join.